# Find the limit and differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

We have the following equality:

$$ f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + a \Delta x \, f(x) - 10 \, b \Delta x $$

with a & b constants. If we take $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}$ , we get a differential equation. My question is, what is the limit? I always have trouble with these types of limits, because in my head I just imagine that all the terms with a factor $\Delta x$ disappear. But in our case, we would get that $f(x) = f(x)$, which is obviously not what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Subtract $f(x)$ from both sides and then divide both sides by $\Delta x$. When you take the limit as $\Delta x\to 0$, you should recognize what the left side becomes.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by @MPW:

Given $$f(x + \Delta x)=f(x) + a\Delta xf(x)-10b\Delta x$$
Which, upon rearrangement yields

$$f(x + \Delta x) - f(x) = a\Delta xf(x) - 10b \Delta x$$

Dividing through by $\Delta x$, gives

$$\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x} =\frac{a\Delta xf(x)-10b\Delta x}{\Delta x}$$

Now taking the limit as $\Delta x \to 0$ yields:

\begin{align*}\lim_{\Delta x \to0} \frac{f(x+ \Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x} &=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{a\Delta xf(x) - 10b \Delta x}{\Delta x} \\ &=\lim_{\Delta x \to0}  \frac{\Delta x(af(x)-10b)}{\Delta x} \\ &= \lim_{\Delta x \to0}  (af(x)-10b) \\ &=af(x)-10b\end{align*}